# Is this cord bend ok on electric range?

Tags: electrical, receptacle, safety, range, cord-and-plug

[image]

Will this be okay for a 40 amp range? The box was set a little too low. I wasn't sure if they bend what cause any issues.

Comment: Isn't it kind of "too late"? The bend's already there, any up-front damage to the contained copper has already been done.

Answer (score 29):

I'm not certain what guage that wire is but many manufacturers will cite a minimum bend radius.
It may or may not be code compliance wherever you are in the world.

I suspect that wire has a minimum bend radius between 1 and 2 inches.

You can achieve that most easily by just rotating the receptacle. The wire will tail upwards, which will look strange, but it will be behind the range so as long as you can maintain the clearance required, you'll be fine.

Comment: Great solution, but I'm going add to your answer.   For the OP: before you do anything, turn off power to the range. Then unplug the outlet, remove the cover plate and then the outlet itself.  Rotate 180 degrees (1/2 way around) and re-install.  The wires will be very stiff and it will take some effort.  Double check the tightness of the wires on the terminals as long as you're in there. replace the cover plate and plug the range back in with the cord pointing up.   Matthew solved your problem, I just wanted to add some additional instructions.

Comment: Depending on location, OP might not be legally allowed to do this change.  Same goes if its a rental.    A 90 degree clockwise rotation might suit better than a 180 degree turn, and is less change for the hefty wiring inside the wall.

Comment: @Criggie a 90° rotation was my first thought, too. But... the outlet _may_ not have fittings to be able to be attached at 90° to its current orientation, while it's almost certain to be able to be fitted at 180°.

Comment: It's not ideal, but given that it's plugged in now, it's fine to just leave it.  Damage happens to cables when they are subject to repeated mechanical stress.  The copper is bent already.  The more you mess with it, the more you will weaken it.  For the number of times you will ever need to plug or unplug that stove in its lifetime it's maybe not worth changing.

Comment: I flipped it 180. Freeman was correct tge box dies not have a way mount 90 degrees

Comment: Yay me! :D @Mstar, please be sure to give this answer a check mark so others know there's a valid solution here.

Answer (score 3):

I can't comment on the correctness of the bend radius, but if you're concerned its too tight, this might help:

I searched around a bit and found this Eaton 5745N which I think would fit as a replacement plug in your situation:

[image]

(Image borrowed from Amazon)

It seems to be available from various online and big-box outlets.

As @FreeMan comments - make sure there is enough of clearance behind the range such that the cable doesn't get overly bent by the back of the range as it it is put back in place.

Comment: This is a great idea that may have unintended consequences... As the oven is pushed back against the wall, the cord that's now sticking straight out will get crimped over at essentially the same angle as in the current situation. I do like the lateral thinking, though.

Comment: @FreeMan There is always a small cavity/space at outlet-level to accomodate the plug, cable, etc.  I think almost all ranges would accomodate this plug at standard outlet heights.

Comment: I did say "may", @J... ;) Well, OK, I started with "may", then switched to "will"...

Comment: +1 now with the added warning (and not because of the shout out).

Comment: According the the GE install instructions  , if in the shaded "zone of acceptability:  as long as it did not stick out more than 2.25" it will fit.   So I a surface mount box would only  JUST be in that zone and ONLY if tipped on its narrow side.  
I mention this since the plug  might be already at the length  once plugged in and  thee wire thickness "stand out" might  mean the cord might want to get  bent  or cause issues pushing it back. I   would never have thought  an oven would be so picky.

Answer (score 0):

That's obviously a moulded plug, but if there's room between the socket and whatever's in front of it, that plug could be changed for one which lets the wire come out of it perpendicularly. Depending on regs where you are, the whole lead may need changing for one with a moulded plug as described.

40 Amps out of a plug top?? Not with 220v...

Another solution might be to dig out whatever is impeding the wire - so there is some room under, where the wire is jammed.

Comment: The NEMA 14-50 (and its close cousin, the NEMA 6-50) is a standard, and quite satisfactory, plug and socket for 50A @ 240V -- it's much bigger and chunkier than the "normal" 15/20A US plugs.  (There's even a 60A version, but it's rarely seen in the wild)

Comment: I have not found one that  is wired with the plug with the wire on the side.

Comment: @Mstar - with the wire coming straight out, at 90 degrees to the wall? In Europe, they're commonplace.

Comment: Wires coming straight out are common in the US as well, but not for this type of plug.  For regular 110/120v plugs, it's more common than not to have the wire coming straight out, but for 230/240v appliance plugs like this (usually reserved for ranges or clothes dryers), it's pretty much always flat against the wall.

Answer (score -1):

So, Matthew's solution works if your plug is symmetric; but what if it isn't? The grounded types mostly arent.

A quick fix is to use an Male-to-Female adapter with a right angle in an appropriate direction, e.g.:

[image]

(if that fits). Then you won't have to worry about the cable's tolerance to nasty bending. A second, similar alternative is using a rotating extension cable:

[image]

Comment: Note that their receptacle and plug are NEMA 10-50 or 14-50, not "B" which is the 5-15...

Comment: @ThreePhaseEel: 1. Thanks, I'm not well-versed in US plugs. 2. I'm not sure who "their" is, but sure. It was just an example.

Comment: I actually did a quick search earlier for a right-angle cord to replace the existing one, and I couldn't find one. I suspect they are available, but not in the Home Depot, etc.

Comment: @einpoklum -- "their" in that case was a reference to the OP, apologies for that :)

Comment: These plugs are rarely rated for 40 amps (typically 5-15A). You'll be shelling out a lot of money for a 40 amp version.

Comment: To put it more succinctly, 15 and 20 amp single phase (120v) adapters like this are fairly ubiquitous. A range will need a 4-prong 230v adapter. The best chance at finding one is going to be an RV cord like [this one](https://www.amazon.com/Ceptics-Extension-Electric-ChargingRV-Generator/dp/B07TCCFFZQ), and the cost and practicality of that is low in this case.

Comment: @Machavity: I merely wanted to illustrate what I meant by a right-angle plug. A chord would be a different, and valid, suggestion, but it's sometimes unwieldy/takes up space you don't want it to.

Comment: @einpoklum a "chord" sounds nice, but I think a "cord" would be more appropriate here. :D

Comment: @FreeMan: Mi no tok english gud :-(

Comment: That's OK, it sounded really good! :):):) `</dad jokes>`

Comment: Matthew's solution works because the **socket's** turned round, not just the plug , most of which *are* non symmetric, especially those with an earth.

Comment: This might still be a better solution than Matthew's for a less technically inclined person, as rotating the socket/receptacle is not something I'd do if I didn't know what I was doing around electricity.

Comment: @Tim: I'm not sure I follow; OP's problem is the socket being set too low.

Comment: @einpoklum - the problem gets solved by Matthew by turning the socket upside down. That then means the plug goes in upside down, and the cable, instead of facing down, where there's hardly room, is facing up, where there's plenty. At that point, the socket could even be ony just above the surface that's in the way.. And - that is already a right angled plug! And - I doubt an adaptor such as you suggest would be rated at 40Amps.

Comment: Both sides of that have the ground pin on top, and the bend is parallel to the ground. It will not increase clearance at all.

Comment: @PeteKirkham: Well, it depends where the surface ends on the side of the picture, but - yeah, you're right. Changed it.